# Angular Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

Tags: angular, spring, typescript

i'm trying to implement a "Create" function to create appointements and i'm also adding the User id who created the appointement,so i created a model of "rendezvous" and "user" but i when i execute the project the console shows an error of **core.mjs:7643 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at CreateRendezvousComponent_Template (create-rendezvous.component.html:45:9)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12114:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:11977:13)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13073:13)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11767:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:12027:13)
at refreshComponent (core.mjs:13073:13)
at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:11767:9)
at refreshView (core.mjs:12027:13)
at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:13027:17)**

the error comes from the HTML of "create-rendezvous" component

```
        <label>Etat</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="etat"
        [(ngModel)]= "rendezvous.etat" name="etat">
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label>user id</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="user.id"
        [(ngModel)]= "rendezvous.user.id" name="user.id">
    </div>
     <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Ajouter</button>

</form>

</div>
```

this is my "Create" function in the "create-rendezvous" component

```
saveRendezVous(){
    this.rendezvousService.createRendezvous(this.rendezvous).subscribe(data=>{
         console.log(data);
         this.goToRendezvousList();
        
    }, 
    error=>console.log(error));
  }
```

and this is my function in the angular service

```
createRendezvous(rendezvous:Rendezvous): Observable<Object>{
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, rendezvous);

  }

i appreciate your help.
```

Comment: Use rendezvous?.user?.id in your template..

Answer (score 0):

undefined would mean that you were trying to call the `id` property of an object that has not been initialized yet. Verify that not only is your rendezvous object is defined and initialized, but that the user object for it is initialized as well.

Likewise verify the user object itself is defined. If it is something that is only defined after some sort of API call to load the data then add some sort of loading state

Comment: i tried initializing the User object but it did'nt work

Comment: @JalelMED can you make a stackblitz and share it for us to see your code fully? You can mock out the results of that get call as well

Answer (score 0):

Try with the Safe navigation operator to all the places where you are using the user.id

For example user?.id